# How to change playing music behavior in a game from playing music through cd-player to playing music through mp3 files?

Tags: pe

I have an old game from the 2000s, and as we know the old games were playing the background music through the CD which means the music files were tracks in the game CD instead of MP3 files as usual nowadays.

The mission is, how to change playing music behavior in the game from playing music through cd-player to playing music through mp3 files that lie in the game directory.

After analyzing the game exe file I found the game uses a function called [mciSendCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd757160(v=vs.85)):

```
MCIERROR mciSendCommand(MCIDEVICEID IDDevice, UINT uMsg, DWORD_PTR fdwCommand, DWORD_PTR dwParam)
```

The problem is that function cannot play the mp3 files and needs to be changed to another function with other codes

[image]

**Do you have ways or ideas to implement this task?**

Comment: I've heard about several projects that replace winmm.dll., for example "ogg-winmm CD Audio Emulator" I found 5 minutes ago, so I can't suggest to use exactly this project - just use it as search words for google.

Comment: Thank you, I tested that project but it did not work with my games.